# Null BuildContext when accessed before Material App

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

When trying to access context, it returns null (Dirty Context). Any suggestions for this. I am trying to directly access after main() function.

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bloc = Provider.of(context);
        return Provider(
      child: StreamBuilder(
          stream:
              Rx.combineLatestList([bloc] as List<Stream<dynamic>>),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              home: MyHomePage(),

           );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that you have received the data from the streambuilder:

```dart
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bloc = Provider.of(context);
        return Provider(
      child: StreamBuilder(
          stream:
              Rx.combineLatestList([bloc] as List<Stream<dynamic>>),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData) {
              return MaterialApp(
                  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                  home: MyHomePage(),
              );
          }
          else
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: actually i am getting issue on this  ```final bloc = Provider.of(context);```